# NGINX API Versioning Techniques

Tags: api, nginx, url-rewriting, versioning

I am looking to use NGINX to handle API versioning.  I thought it would be as simple as this to handle sending the traffic to different URLS:

```
    location = /1.0/* {
        root = /var/www/html/version_1.0/public;
    }
    location = /1.1/* {
        root = /var/www/html/version_1.1/public;
    }
```

I would then write some form of rewrite to strip out the 1.0/ or 1.1/ from the URL.  Is that correct?  Anyways, the location method doesn't work.  Is my syntax off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure this is not about [matching order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> nginx first searches for the most specific location given by literal strings regardless of the listed order. In the configuration above the only literal location is “`/`” and since it matches any request it will be used as a last resort.
>   Then nginx checks locations given by regular expression in the order listed in the configuration file. The first matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this location.
>   If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses the most specific literal location found earlier.

You can try [a location directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location), testing for the literal you want, and preventing any regex to be checked:

```
location ^~ /1.0/ {
  # matches any query beginning with /1.0/ and halts searching,
  # so regular expressions will not be checked.
  [ configuration C ] 
}
```

Then you can check [rewrite procedures](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

Comment: ^~ isn't a regex location, it's a prefix location that won't be overridden by a regex location.  Your comment in the location says as much.

Comment: @kolbyjack: good point, I have edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: "location ^~ /1.0/" and "location = /1.0/" (OP's config without the "*") are much the same thing.

Comment: @Dayo I suspect as much, but I wanted to be sure, by suggesting the OP to try that.

Comment: @VonC On review of the docs, "location ^~ /xyz/" is indeed the more appropriate. "location = /xyz/" is for an exact match and while the OP added a "*" to serve as a wildcard, that isn't how it works and he needs location ^~ /xyz/ as you rightly pointed out.

Comment: @Dayo: ok, so hopefully the OP will confirm that :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I was testing this stuff and wanted to give confirmation.  You are right, as this method works. Thanks a lot.  The rewrites are still busted, but for this thread, you are 100% on point.  Thanks!